# Django process form in steps

Tags: python, django, forms, process

[image]
Hello everyone, i'm trying to complete profiles after registration in Django.
So once the user is registered, he uses the following **steps**:

Step 1: Registration (Works)

**Step 2**: Select University(Shows a select with the universities but it has to pass the selected university in order to filter courses in step 3)

**Step 3**: Select Course and add Year. Here the user will be able to select one course and enter his year of study. Then the year of study will be stored in studies_student(year field). And also I store the course that the student selected by `enrolled_id`.

What I need is to send the **university** from step 2 to step 3, filter courses and submit the `enrolled_id` and `year`.

views.py

```
def step2(request):
    universities = University.objects.order_by('name').distinct()
    return render_to_response("registration/step2.html", {'universities': universities},  RequestContext(request))


def step3(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Enroll(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render_to_response("registration/complete.html", {'courses': courses},  RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = Enroll()

    args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'registration/complete.html')


def complete(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/complete.html')
```

forms.py

```
class Enroll(forms.ModelForm):
    course = forms.ChoiceField()
    year = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),
                                          MaxValueValidator(7)])

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('year',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        student = super(Student, self).save(commit=False)

        if commit:
            student.save()

        return student
```

Sorry for the long text, but i'm trying to do this for days so I tried to explain what i'm aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'll strongly advise to create separete models for `University` and `Course`.
you can create a `ForeignKey` for University in Course table

```
class University(forms.ModelForm):
      //university attributes

class Course(forms.ModelForm):
     //course attrbutes
     university = forms.ForeignKey('University')
```

When you have a `course` object, you can get corresponding `university` object like

```
course_obj.university
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Hi Naveen! I already have 2 separate models of **University** and **Course** as you can see in the db image. So is there any way that I can pass the selected **University** from step 2 to step 3 and filter **courses** by **university**?

Comment: remodel you Course model add ForeignKey for university... once you have you can say get say to Course "get all courses where universty name or id is xyz"

Comment: I already have a ForeignKey for University in Course model. The issue I can't pass it from the form. I read this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/) but I'm really stack.

Comment: can you please post the all models you are using ?

Comment: Sure! Here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/wmfVfbxL). Thank you in advance for helping me! Really appreciate it!

Comment: when a university is selected in step2 make a ajax request to get the courses related to university and fill the courses from the result of step2 in step3

Comment: Isn't there a way to pass the selected object from step 2 to step 3 and filter courses by university?